# Font awesome borders

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I'm trying to add a border to my font awesome icons like the picture below: 
[image]

Yes i managed to do it, but this is not the right way to go I'll explain you why after you see my code:

Html:

```
        <div id= "contact">


        <i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-2x"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-phone fa-2x"></i>

       </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
/*font awesome*/

i.fa-envelope-o {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
   display: inline-block;
   border:2px solid white;
  border-radius: 60px;

}
.fa-envelope-o {

  padding-top: 5px;
}

i.fa-phone {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
   display: inline-block;
   border:2px solid white;
  border-radius: 60px;

}

.fa-phone {

  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

As you can see this is not the right way, what if i have to use the envelope icon once again but without a border? And to center it i had to use padding top. Is there a cleaner way to do this? I don't want to use the i tag alone, since the text above uses it aswel for, for example:

`<p><i>hello</i></p>`

Thanks in advance,
Kevin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```css
div#contact {
  background-color: black;
}
#contact i.fa {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 60px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.2/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div id= "contact">


        <i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-2x"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-phone fa-2x"></i>

       </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new css class and use both the font-awesome class and your custom one. For example:

```
<i class="fa fa-envelope-o custom-envelope fa-2x"></i>
```

This will apply the custom styles you wanted, such as the `border-radius`, `padding`, etc.

If you then want to use the default style for an icon, just omit this extra class and leave the font-awesome class in:

```
<i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-2x"></i>
```

#### Demo

```css
i.custom-envelope {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 60px;
}
.custom-envelope {
  padding-top: 5px;
}
#contact {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.2/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div id="contact">
  Custom: <i class="fa fa-envelope-o custom-envelope fa-2x"></i>
  <br>
  Default: <i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-2x"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: This works fine nice :) I made "custom-envelope" > "border-icon" and applied it on both icons.